# Understanding the Trade-offs Between Hardware and Software Implementations for Communication Protocols in Embedded Systems

Tags: embedded, communication, protocol

I am currently learning about embedded systems and am keen to understand the trade-offs between using dedicated hardware blocks and software implementations for communication protocols like UART, SPI, and I2C.

From what I've gathered:

1. Hardware-based communication is typically faster since it operates
   independently of CPU cycles.
2. Employing dedicated hardware for communication allows the CPU to
   focus on other tasks, thus enhancing overall system performance.

However, I'm concerned about the loss of flexibility and the potential costs associated with hardware-based solutions. What if I want to switch to a different communication protocol in the future? Or what if I want a single component to communicate with multiple other components, each using a different protocol?

Software-based approaches seem more flexible in this regard. Many Internet protocols like TCP/IP, HTTP, and FTP are software-based and their flexibility appears to outweigh their potential drawbacks. I often hear the argument that software-based approaches are "not as fast," but I wonder if speed is really the paramount concern. Most processors are not fully utilized most of the time, and not all systems have stringent performance requirements.

My questions are:

- Are there industry-specific preferences for choosing hardware over
  software, or vice versa, for communication protocols in embedded
  systems?
- Is the potential loss of speed in software-based communications often
  a deal-breaker in professional settings?

I'm just trying to understand the rationale behind all of this.

Comment: This is way too broad a question for this site, you could write entire books on this subject and not cover it all. It really depends on your application and what your design goals are. Many MCUs have multiple hardware peripherals to talk different protocols.

Comment: And since you don't even take DMA in account this whole question has pretty flawed reasoning... unless you consider DMA a "hardware solution". DMA is no longer something exotic only available on the most high-end MCUs.

Comment: Decoding **IR remote codes** is done with software (I've yet to see a microcontroller include a hardware module)....you should be prepared to use both hardware/software solutions in serial communication. In this case, speed is likely not an issue. And in this case, serial bit-encoding is done many different ways...making flexible software the preferred choice.

Comment: It's always worth looking at the commercial aspect, and costing can be very complex: Do think about the magic number N (how many are we making) and the difference between design-costs (one off) and per-unit costs.  Very frequently, for software, the design-costs are low (lots of libraries) and the per-unit costs are close to zero.  Unless N is high, it's often not worth the design-costs or the per-unit costs of hardware.

Comment: Did you want to say design-costs for software is high or am I missing something? @jonathanjo

Comment: I'm saying that design cost for software is usually lower than hardware for comparable complexity.  It is in general a very difficult topic, especially if you take into account FPGAs and other "soft hardware"; and often complex hardware requires complex software.  Often this is modelled as an abstract multidimensional space, with walls (eg "too expensive", "too slow", "too similar") demarcating a viable product zone.  If you can move products towards dimensions you're good at (eg "fast prototype turnaround") your organisation will benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always need some kind of hardware to convert from the electrical signal to the logical information your CPU can deal with in software; so, you're drawing a dichtomy here that just can't exist.

Taking the "simplest" of the examples you have: SPI. The electrical protocol is very simple: the receiver samples the value of the data line at the rising edge of clock. That's it. That's how "this is a bit value in SPI" is defined.

Your software can't "sample" an electrical signal. It needs to ask a peripheral for its state. So your software implementation would have to either poll the clock line input peripheral to wait for a rising edge, then ask the data line what the state is, **or** it could program a hardware peripheral to latch the value of the data line into a register once there's a rising edge. And fun fact, that's exactly an SPI peripheral. The polling method will be hard to make standards-compliant, as there'd be an indefinite latency between edge and observation of edge. Also, you have to realize that an SPI peripheral is really just an edge-controlled flipflop (+shift register); that's the same as a lot of the logic of your CPU is anyways; there's no sensible reason you'd want to do this in software. This is really very little logic.

On the other hand, adding the CPU speed and low latency necessary to support doing things like SPI, I²C and UART purely in software is way more complicated – so for almost all use cases, the tendency is to make a few of these dedicated implementations and stick them on the chip, whether the user will need them or not.

Other buses get more complicated, and there's often complicated state machines, where having a mixture of hardware implementation and software driver is desirable, and boundaries are different between these for different implementations. But: the truth remains that you need the hardware anyways to make sense of the electrical levels. And in case of SPI, the way from "can detect a line state at the time specified by the protocol" to "an SPI hardware receiver" is really short.

You're comparing network / application protocols to electrical protocols, but that comparison doesn't work out: for network protocols, the data is already in the computer (you're literally *dozens* of software layers above the hardware once you can say "this packet is a HTTP packet" in your application); and the act of sampling the ethernet interface to get the ethernet packets, which contain the bits, is done in hardware. (Also, note that your claims are partially wrong: where it actually matters in terms of speed and power consumption, partial TCP/IP hardware implementations are very much a thing.)

> I often hear the argument that software-based approaches are "not as fast," but I wonder if speed is really the paramount concern.

If technical feasibility doesn't rule out software at all, yes, it is (together with the power consumption of a complex general purpose CPU doing something asynchronously at high clock rates that a small, hardware state machine could have done bus-synchronously at lower rates, could have done.)

> Are there industry-specific preferences for choosing hardware over software, or vice versa, for communication protocols in embedded systems?

*Engineering, based on analysis of the situation* is the industry-preferred method of choosing solutions; see my explanations above!

> Is the potential loss of speed in software-based communications often a deal-breaker in professional settings?

If "Deal-breaker" is an euphemism for "it's impossible", yes. You simply can't build a CPU that could sample a USB3.0 data line fast enough in software. And you would have to implement the clock recovery, timing control, equalization … in software as well! CPUs that fast simply do not exist. And that's USB3.0, a > 10 year old standard. You have to realize that between your CPU core and your USB3.0 controller, there's another bus - for example, PCIe v4, which will be even faster.

Comment: A more in-depth explanation than I expected. Thank you very much. I always assumed that since these are actual hardware components, they would be costly, both in terms of economics and complexity, especially considering that software is essentially free. However, if implementing these protocols is cost-effective in both of these aspects, then it does make more sense. Additionally, I believed that the simplest of these protocols would be UART, which, as far as I know, is sometimes implemented without dedicated hardware.

Comment: The hardware support usually boils down to a clocked register and some logic that tells apart data and synchronisation. If the protocol is asynchronous, also a clock rate generator. Higher levels of hardware support can be found when the µC is not meant to be the initiator of a transfer. For example, the extra hardware could sort out the I²C address from the start of a transfer and only trigger an interrupt in the CPU if it matches the address the CPU has said it wants to listen to. That reduces the load on the individual CPU a lot if the I²C bus has a lot of components connected to it.

Comment: @merovingian an UART receivers is orders of magnitude more complex than a simple shift register, which is all that an SPI receiver is. As the name suggests, the receiver is asynchronous and has to do its own timing recovery! I've seen a UART implemented in software *once* in my life, and that was on a dedicated soft-CPU core in an FPGA, and it really did a really small subset of what a full UART receiver is supposed to be able to do. But sure, if you need at most a couple kbaud, then you might do it in software.

Answer (score -1):

The 3 interface types UART, SPI, and I2C have distinct feature sets and are not interchangeable. Therefore you would not switch from one to the other in the future, just as you would not use salt and pepper interchangeably.

In your quest to learn about embedded systems, you should study the "OSI model". It describes in a disciplined way how communication is accomplished at different layers in a technology stack, and what purpose each distinct layer has.

It doesn't make sense to suggest that HTTP might be an alternative to UART, because they refer to different OSI layers. It is a meaningless comparison, just as suggesting that we shouldn't use letters and punctuation to write poetry, but blog publishing software.

The OSI model describes computer communications just as language describes human communication. Language has many layers, from glyphs and punctuation, to spelling, grammar, semantics, composition, style, etc, which are not meaningfully interchanged. It's not meaningful to ask about tradeoffs between punctuation and semantics, nor about tradeoffs between I2C and FTP.

Comment: How did you infer from this question that I was suggesting the use of HTTP over UART? It was simply an example of a software protocol.

Comment: You asked about "preferences for choosing hardware over software or vice versa", and gave TCP/IP, HTTP and FTP as examples of software protocols, and UART, SPI and I2C as examples of hardware protocols. Then you directly compared them on the basis of flexibility and cost. It was not so much inference, but a direct reading of your question.

Comment: I was just implying that software protocols also exist and work. I didn't imply to use UART over HTTP or FTP.

Comment: I think you didn't merely imply that software protocols exist, you plainly stated it. I fully understand that it would not make sense to compare UART to HTTP, but that's what you did in your question, although you separated the two terms by a few lines of additional text. My reading of it, is that in your mind, HTTP can be a replacement for hardware protocols like UART, SPI and I2C. That's how your question reads to me.